# Is I understand condition properly?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

There is such example

$${A = \{1, 2, \{1\}, \{2, \varnothing\}\}}, B = \{1, 2, \varnothing, \{\varnothing\}, \{2\}\}$$

and such condition

$${\{x\} \in B - A  \ or \ x\in A \to x = 2}$$

I am not clearly understand from the one hand number 2 is really fit to condition, because ${\{2\} \in B - A}$ is true and x = 2, so ${true \to true}$ is true

But from other hand if look at this as every variable from set B - A should came to x = 2, it is false. But anyway as I know ${false \to false}$ is true, just ${true \to false}$ give false.

So, I am I little bit confused how correctly I need to look at this condition and what answer is correct, examples appreciate

**EDIT**

also there is such condition

$${(x \in B - A  \ and \  x \subseteq A) \to x = \varnothing}$$

I know that this condition is false, but why?

So, ${B - A = \{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}, \{2\}\}}$, let's take first value from this set - ${\varnothing}$, so in the left part ${x \in B - A  \ and \  x \subseteq A}$ - it is true as well as in the right part ${x = \varnothing}$, so ${true \to true}$ is true.

Ok, let's take second value from thins set - ${B - A}$ is ${\{\varnothing\}}$ on the left part it will be false as well as on the right part it will be false, so ${false\to false}$ anyway is true.

The same with the last one from this set ${B - A}$ -  ${\{2\}}$, left part false, right part false ${false\to false}$ anyway is true.

So, this condition should be true.

What am I missing? Why right answer is false?

Comment: Your perplexity is correct; $1 \in A$ but $1=2$ is false.

Comment: If you are asking whether the statement is true or false, it is ambiguous to me whether this is $(\{x\}\in B\setminus A~\text{or}~x\in A)\implies x=2$ or if this is $\{x\}\in B\setminus A~\text{or}~(x\in A\implies x = 2)$.  Both of these however are false.  Consider what happens when $x=1$.  You have that $\{1\}$ is not in $B\setminus A$ so that part is false.  Then you have $1\in A$ is true.  Despite both of these things however, $x=2$ is false since $1\neq 2$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA could you please take a look at my edit.

Comment: @JMoravitz could you please take a look at my edit..

Comment: You have the same ambiguity in your second question included after the edit.  Is this meant to be $(P\wedge Q)\implies R$ or is this meant to be $P\wedge (Q\implies R)$?

Comment: In either event... $\{2\}$ is an element of $B\setminus A$ and is a subset of $A$, however $\{2\}\neq \emptyset$

Comment: The issue is: whenever the statement has variable $x$, we assume that an universal quantifier is implicitly assumed: "for every $x$, if $x \in \ldots$, then $x=2$".